# No Resources Found for @drawable/dark_header_dither

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-theme, android-styles

I'm trying to stylize the PreferenceCategory elements in my Settings screen. Using the code below, I'm able to change the text color, but I lose the dark grey separator line. I looked at the source for Widget.TextView.ListSeparator and saw that it uses a drawable for the background. If I try to apply the same drawable, I get an error saying "No resource found that matches the given name... @drawable/dark_header_dither"

How do I get this to work with a separator line?

```
<style name="Widget.TextView.ListSeparator" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
</style>

<style name="PreferenceListHeader" parent="Widget.TextView.ListSeparator">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/dark_header_dither</item> <!--Problem! -->
    <item name="android:textColor">#0288d1</item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is due to the reason that you don't have dark_header_dither file in your drawable resource folder. "@drawable/file" searches file in your drawable folder in resource, but it can't find it there. You can add your own dithered image in drawable folder and refer it by "@drawable/your_dithered_image_name"

Hope this helps ...

**Edit** :

I am not sure why I am unable to refer to this file, but a work around is to add your own xml file with same contents as dark_header_dither.xml file.

After tracking this drawable file, I got its contents :

```
  <nine-patch xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:src="@android:drawable/dark_header"
     android:dither="true"
  />
```

Create a file in your drawable resource folder with the name "dark_header_dither.xml" and add the above content.

Now, you will be able to refer it without any trouble....

Comment: I figured that much... but where is the drawable that it uses by default when I don't edit this style? I'd like to simply use that one, but I can't find it.

Comment: This helped! Oddly, this worked, but the background I got was a solid color. When I look at the dark_header.9.png, it looks like a vertical line. I don't know how it works by default, but when implemented the way I tried, it drew that vertical line across instead of putting a horizontal line at the bottom. I've decided to use your solution, but with my own custom .9.png.